# I am trying to filter results from an array in elasticsearch is a nested fields, but the results are not as expected

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to filter results for store number 1 which are not in a specific date range which in my case is from 2023-01-27 to 2023-07-27, but the result hits are not including which should have.
For example, store number does not have transaction between 2023-01-27 to 2023-07-27, but other store number has transaction in the above date range and is excluding from the result.

txn_info is a nested object which is an array of objects which has transaction date and store number similar to

[data structure in elastic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gate8.png)

Basically, I should be able to filter based on combination of both store number and txn_date (if store number is one and for str num 1, txn_date should not be between 2023-01-27 to 2023-07-27

My query:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD9RI.png)

Comment: Avoid using images. Use the tools to add code snippets in the question. Make it easy for those who will reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "txn_info",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "txn_info.store_number": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ], 
          "must_not": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "txn_info.txt_date": {
                        "gte": "2021-08-09",
                        "lte": "2021-08-09"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```